# Python: Spyder figure window - can't copy or save

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am running Spyder v3.2.4 in Windows 10.

I have gone to Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics Backend > Automatic to get my graphs/figures in separate windows. My question is, can I change the window type used to display these graphics? For example, in the window style I have I cannot copy or print the graphic directly. Instead having to save first. Is there a way around this?

The window style I have is:

[image: window title bar]

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Plot windows are not generated nor handled by Spyder but by Matplotlib. Unfortunately (as you correctly point out) you can only save plots in them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment